# Checkbox field that add a subscription product and change prices of other products

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce checkout section, I am trying to add a checkbox that adds an additional subscription product. It is working fine and I took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585490/checkbox-field-that-add-to-cart-a-product-in-woocommerce-checkout-page/#answer-53585810)

One more requirement is that if there are other products in the cart then I want to change each product prices based on custom fields and new prices should display in the checkout.
Thanks in advance.

I used this code and working fine but product price is not changing in PayPal payment page.

```
        // Display a custom checkout field
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_terms_and_conditions', 'custom_checkbox_checkout_field' );
    function custom_checkbox_checkout_field() {
        $value = WC()->session->get('add_a_product');

        woocommerce_form_field( 'cb_add_product', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'label'         => '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . __('Please check here to get VIP Membership'),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        ), $value == 'yes' ? true : false );
    }


    // The jQuery Ajax request
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_custom_jquery_script' );
    function checkout_custom_jquery_script() {
        // Only checkout page
        if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):

        // Remove "ship_different" custom WC session on load
        if( WC()->session->get('add_a_product') ){
            WC()->session->__unset('add_a_product');
        }
        if( WC()->session->get('product_added_key') ){
            WC()->session->__unset('product_added_key');
        }
        // jQuery Ajax code
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( function($){
            if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined')
                return false;

            $('form.checkout').on( 'change', '#cb_add_product', function(){
                var value = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 'yes' : 'no';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        'action': 'add_a_product',
                        'add_a_product': value,
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                        //console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
        endif;
    }

    // The Wordpress Ajax PHP receiver
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_a_product', 'checkout_ajax_add_a_product' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_a_product', 'checkout_ajax_add_a_product' );
    function checkout_ajax_add_a_product() {
        if ( isset($_POST['add_a_product']) ){
            WC()->session->set('add_a_product', esc_attr($_POST['add_a_product']));
            echo $_POST['add_a_product'];
        }
        die();
    }

    // Add remove free product
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adding_removing_specific_product' );
    function adding_removing_specific_product( $cart ) {
        if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
            return;

        if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
            return;

        // HERE the specific Product ID
        $product_id = 179;

        if( WC()->session->get('add_a_product') == 'yes' && ! WC()->session->get('product_added_key') )
        {

        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $cart_item_key = $cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            WC()->session->set('product_added_key', $cart_item_key);

             // get the product id (or the variation id)
             $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

             // GET THE NEW PRICE (code to be replace by yours)
             $new_price = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'pro_price_extra_info', true );

             // Updated cart item price
             $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval( $new_price ) );
        }
        }
        elseif( WC()->session->get('add_a_product') == 'no' && WC()->session->get('product_added_key') )
        {
            $cart_item_key = WC()->session->get('product_added_key');
            $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            WC()->session->__unset('product_added_key');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for my above post. It might help others in future.

```
            // Display a custom checkout field
            add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_terms_and_conditions', 'custom_checkbox_checkout_field' );
            function custom_checkbox_checkout_field() {
                $value = WC()->session->get('add_a_product');

                woocommerce_form_field( 'cb_add_product', array(
                    'type'          => 'checkbox',
                    'label'         => '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . __('Please check here to get VIP Membership'),
                    'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
                ), $value == 'yes' ? true : false );
            }


            // The jQuery Ajax request
            add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_custom_jquery_script' );
            function checkout_custom_jquery_script() {
                // Only checkout page
                if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):

                // Remove "ship_different" custom WC session on load
                if( WC()->session->get('add_a_product') ){
                    WC()->session->__unset('add_a_product');
                }
                if( WC()->session->get('product_added_key') ){
                    WC()->session->__unset('product_added_key');
                }
                // jQuery Ajax code
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery( function($){
                    if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined')
                        return false;

                    $('form.checkout').on( 'change', '#cb_add_product', function(){
                        var value = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 'yes' : 'no';

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                            data: {
                                'action': 'add_a_product',
                                'add_a_product': value,
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                                //console.log(result);
                            }
                        });

                        if(value == 'no'){
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>
                <?php
                endif;
            }

            // The Wordpress Ajax PHP receiver
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_a_product', 'checkout_ajax_add_a_product' );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_a_product', 'checkout_ajax_add_a_product' );
            function checkout_ajax_add_a_product() {
                if ( isset($_POST['add_a_product']) ){
                    WC()->session->set('add_a_product', esc_attr($_POST['add_a_product']));
                    echo $_POST['add_a_product'];
                }
                die();
            }

            // Add remove free product
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adding_removing_specific_product' );
            function adding_removing_specific_product( $cart ) {
                if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
                    return;

                if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
                    return;

                $has_sub = wcs_user_has_subscription( '', '179', 'active' );

                $product_id = 179;

                if( WC()->session->get('add_a_product') == 'yes' && ! WC()->session->get('product_added_key') ){
                    // HERE the specific Product ID


                    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {       

                         // get the product id (or the variation id)
                         $product_idnew = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
                         // GET THE NEW PRICE (code to be replace by yours)
                         $new_price = get_post_meta( $product_idnew, 'pro_price_extra_info', true );
                         $old_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

                         if($new_price == NULL){
                            $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval( $old_price ) );
                         } else {
                            $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval( $new_price ) );
                         }

                    }

                    $cart_item_key = $cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
                    WC()->session->set('product_added_key', $cart_item_key);


                } elseif( WC()->session->get('add_a_product') == 'no' && WC()->session->get('product_added_key') ) {

                    $cart_item_key = WC()->session->get('product_added_key');
                    $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );      
                    WC()->session->__unset('product_added_key');        

                }elseif ( $has_sub ) {
                    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {       

                         // get the product id (or the variation id)
                         $product_idnew = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
                         // GET THE NEW PRICE (code to be replace by yours)
                         $new_price = get_post_meta( $product_idnew, 'pro_price_extra_info', true );
                            $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval( $new_price ) );

                    }
                }

            }
            function woo_in_cart($product_id) {
                global $woocommerce;         
                foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
                    $_product = $val['data'];

                    if($product_id == $_product->id ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }         
                return false;
            }
            add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'adding_vip_product' );
            function adding_vip_product( $cart ) {
                $product_id = 179;
                if(woo_in_cart($product_id) ) {

                    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {       

                         // get the product id (or the variation id)
                         $product_idnew = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
                         // GET THE NEW PRICE (code to be replace by yours)
                         $new_price = get_post_meta( $product_idnew, 'pro_price_extra_info', true );
                         if($new_price != 0){
                            $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval( $new_price ) );
                         }

                    }

                }
            }
```